# Angular, http return double int array

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

When I return a double/two dimensional array from my MVC project in my Angular app it only returns a single array. How do I return a double array from my MVC controller to my Angular app?

```
   function getStatusView() {

    dataFactory.getStatusView()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.statusview = response.data.StatusViewList;
            $scope.modelList = response.data.ModelList;
            $scope.modelClustersList = response.data.ModelCLustersList;
            $scope.turbineNumberDistinct = response.data.TurbineNumbersDistinct;
            $scope.alarmArray = response.data.statusArray;

            }, function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
        });
}



   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetStatusView()
    {
        model.statusArray = new int[model.ModelList.Count, model.StatusViewList.Count];

        var statuslinesWithAlarm = statusView.Where(p => p.AlarmLevel> 0).ToList();

        foreach (var statuslineWithAlarm in statuslinesWithAlarm)
        {
            var turbineIndex = model.StatusViewList.Select(p => p.TurbineNumber).ToList().IndexOf(statuslineWithAlarm.TurbineNumber);
            var modelIndex = model.ModelList.IndexOf(statuslineWithAlarm.ModelName);

            model.statusArray[modelIndex,turbineIndex] = 1;

        }
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript does not know about this kind of 2D arrays, so you will not get the expected result after deserialization. Instead declare your model as an array of arrays. Something like:

```
var model = new int[][] { new [] { ... }, new [] { ... }, new [] { ... } }
```

[Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) overcomes this issue by correctly serializing multiple dimension arrays into arrays of arrays:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you!